# How can I match requests for known mime types containing query strings, in nginx?

Tags: nginx, web-server, pattern-matching

I'm using nginx to serve assets statically, and also route all non-asset requests to a PHP front controller.  I have a `location` block that looks like:

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php;
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

From what I understand, this should first try to match the request against any known MIME types, and if no matching file is found, it should try the request against my PHP `location` block (not shown).

This works great if I want to visit `http://example.com/css/owls.css`, but if I try to visit `http://example.com/css/owls.css?t=_423632636`, it doesn't recognize the "extension" and so tries to pass the request to my PHP entry point (which of course, fails).

How can I tell nginx that a request for `http://example.com/css/owls.css?t=_423632636` (or any other query string that follows a valid MIME type) should first try to match the static file `css/owls.css`?

If the file (without the query string) does not exist, then it should fall back to the PHP `try_files` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx does this automatically for me, with the try_files line below. Note you're using $request_uri instead of $uri. Try changing that. first.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

If that doesn't solve your problem please edit your question to include your entire nginx.conf and relevant server block.

Comment: Very good to know.  So `$uri` is just `$request_uri` with the query string chopped off?

Comment: Yes http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri